# Make the angle of box italic rounded using css only

Tags: html, css

How to make the angle of box italic rounded similar the blue box in this image:

[image]

can do that using CSS only? [no-canvas]

```css
body {background-color: #eee}

#name {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* - - - - - - - - - - - */
  border: 3px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="name">Something</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the css property `transform: skew`

I also added a span inside your div so that the text is not in italic.

```css
body {background-color: #eee}

#name {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  /* - - - - - - - - - - - */
  border: 3px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 0 8px 0 8px;
}
#name>span {
  transform: skew(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="name"><span>Something</span></div>
```

If you want the left border to stay straight, you can try this :

```css
body {background-color: #eee}

#container {
  border-left: 3px solid #3498db;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#name {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  /* - - - - - - - - - - - */
  border: 3px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 0 8px 0 8px;
}
#name>span {
  transform: skew(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="name" style="margin-left:-50px;"><span>Something</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right. I was editing my answer to avoid that behavior. Now the text isn't in italic anymore

Comment: that's good now, thanks very much, I hope to find another solution for the left of the box, t want it as straight, <3

Comment: You can wrap the div with a container having the CSS properties "border-left: 3px solid #3498db; overflow:hidden", and add a "margin-left:-50px" to your #name div

Comment: I tried it, but the left border of text-box cuts italic as well

Comment: I edited the answer. It looks working with the given snippet